# Advice on combining two XML feeds together - own3d/twitch.tv

Tags: php, xml, api

I am working on a small project to display live streams for Dota 2, League of Legends and StarCraft 2 and was using a 3rd party hosted api that had both feeds from Twitch.tv and own3d - I couldn't of been happier, until they shut down their servers!

I tried merging them together with Yahoo pipes but didn't have much luck!
These are the two feeds I am working with:

Twitch.tv/justin.tv - http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.xml?category=gaming&limit=15

Own3d - http://api.own3d.tv/live?limit=15

Here is my attempt at combining the two feeds, by just listing them on top of each other. Its a temporary solution but they are not sorted by live viewers (which is something I would like to do) -

The current script I have:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th colspan="4" class="streamheader">Current live Sstreams</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>

<?php

$xmlFileData2 = file_get_contents("http://api.own3d.tv/live?limit=15");

$xmlData2 = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlFileData2);

foreach($xmlData2->channel->item as $item) 

if ($item->misc['game'] == 'Dota 2' OR $item->misc['game'] == 'League of Legends' OR $item->misc['game'] == 'StarCraft II') {

{

$titlelimit = $item->title;

$title = substr($titlelimit,0,20);

echo "<tr><td>";

if ($item->misc['game'] == 'League of Legends')
echo"<img src='http://localhost/ae/wp-content/themes/ae/img/lol.jpg' /></td><td>";
elseif ($item->misc['game'] == 'StarCraft II')
echo"<img src='http://localhost/ae/wp-content/themes/ae/img/sc2.jpg' /></td><td>";
elseif ($item->misc['game'] == 'Dota 2')
echo"<img src='http://localhost/ae/wp-content/themes/ae/img/dota2.jpg' /></td><td>";

else
echo "none";

echo "<a href='";
$link = $item->link;             
$findthis ="/www.own3d.tv/live/"; 
$replacement ="ae/stream/"; 
echo str_replace ($findthis, $replacement, $link);
echo "'>";
echo $title;
echo "</a></td><td>";
$author = $item->author;             
$find ="/rss@own3d.tv/"; 
$replace =""; 
echo preg_replace ($find, $replace, $author);
echo "<td>";
echo $item->misc['viewers']; 
echo "</td> </tr>";

}
}
else
{
echo "";
}

$xmlFileData1 = file_get_contents("http://api.justin.tv/api/stream/list.xml?category=gaming&limit=15");

$xmlData1 = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlFileData1);

foreach($xmlData1->stream as $itemtwitch) {

$game = $itemtwitch->meta_game;

$sc2 = "StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty";

if ($itemtwitch->meta_game == 'Dota 2' OR $itemtwitch->meta_game == 'League of Legends' OR $itemtwitch->meta_game == 'StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty') {
{
echo "<tr><td>";

$titlelimittwitch = $itemtwitch->title;

$titlelimittwitch = substr($titlelimittwitch,0,20);

if ($itemtwitch->meta_game == 'League of Legends')
echo"<img src='http://localhost/ae/wp-content/themes/ae/img/lol.jpg' /></td><td>";
elseif ($itemtwitch->meta_game == 'StarCraft II: Wings of Liberty')
echo"<img src='http://localhost/ae/wp-content/themes/ae/img/sc2.jpg' /></td><td>";
elseif ($itemtwitch->meta_game == 'Dota 2')
echo"<img src='http://localhost/ae/wp-content/themes/ae/img/dota2.jpg' /></td><td>";
else
echo "none";

$data = $itemtwitch->name;
$find ="/live_user_/";
$replace ="";
echo "<a href='";
echo "http://localhost/ae/stream/";
echo preg_replace ($find, $replace, $data);
echo "''>";
echo "$titlelimittwitch";
//print(" - " . $itemtwitch->meta_game . "");
echo "</a></td><td>";
echo preg_replace ($find, $replace, $data);
print("</td><td>" . $itemtwitch->channel_count . "</td></tr>");
}
}
else {
echo "";
}
}
?>

<tr>

<th colspan="4" class="streamheader centered">View all streams</th>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
```

Any guidance or being pointed in the right direction would be fantastic.

Cheers!

Comment: I've made a library called Streamtastic for JUST this purpose. :) It's written in C#, but hopefully you'll get the gist of it and how to use it. https://github.com/sergiotapia/Streamtastic

Comment: This looks fantastic, but I have no experience in C# or compiling apps so I will have to do a bit of research on getting this working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan, you will need to add both sets of information(own3d/twitch) to the same array, then sort it. Say you add them to an array named $streamArray you would use the following code to then sort them by viewers.

```
foreach ($streamArray as $key => $row) {
 $viewers[$key] = $row['viewers'];
}

array_multisort($viewers, SORT_DESC, SORT_NUMERIC, $streamArray);
```

I have developed a similar setup at http://halfw.com/streams.php

If you have any questions just let me know!

Comment: Oh my! Joseph that is fantastic (your example that is!)! I have had trouble combining them both in an array as the fields used to store information are different between the two APIs - this is currently what I had before I lost access to the api I was using (http://goo.gl/PE0bC) - The aim of this whole project is for me to learn but this has been driving me nuts for about 2 weeks!

Comment: I managed to combine both of the arrays, but it takes some time to load - http://pastebin.com/f9kE0QMW - but unsure how to sort by viewers if one uses view_count and the other uses viewers

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like Streamtastic (*disclaimer: I wrote it*) to get latest and top viewed streams for both Own3d and Twitch.tv

https://github.com/sergiotapia/Streamtastic

Usage is very simple:

### **Own3d Examples:**

```
StreamFinder own3dStreamtastic = new StreamFinder(new Own3dStreamRepository());

// Let's find the most viewed streamers in general.
var topStreamers = own3dStreamtastic.FindTopViewedStreams();
foreach (var stream in topStreamers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - Viewers: {1}", stream.Title, stream.ViewerCount));
}

// You can find the top viewed streamers for any game Own3d supports.
// For example, League of Legends.
var topStreamersForLeagueOfLegends = own3dStreamtastic.FindTopViewedStreamsByGame("League+of+Legends");
foreach (var stream in topStreamersForLeagueOfLegends)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - Viewers: {1}", stream.Title, stream.ViewerCount));
}

// Or how about League of Legends.
var topStreamersForLol = own3dStreamtastic.FindTopViewedStreamsByGame("League+of+Legends");
foreach (var stream in topStreamersForLol)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} - Viewers: {1}", stream.Title, stream.ViewerCount));
}
```

Since you're using PHP, just run this application and save results to the database. Then have your PHP program just fetch results from the database.